# Maximizing $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{10}$, where each $x_i$ lies between $-1$ and $1$, and $x_1^3+x_2^3+\cdots+x_{10}^3=0$

Tags: trigonometry

> Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{10}$ be ten quantities each lying between $-1$ and $1$, and the sum of cubes of these ten quantities is zero. Find the maximum value of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{10}$.

I have tried substituting $x_1=\sin(y_1)$, $x_2=\sin(y_2)$, and so on,  and then used the identity for $\sin 3x$ to simplify the cubes leading to
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots x_{10} = \frac13 (\sin 3y_1 + \sin 3y_2 +\cdots + \sin 3y_{10})$$
Now is the statement
$$\frac13 (\sin 3y_1 + \sin 3y_2 +\cdots + \sin 3y_{10}) \leq \frac{10}{3}$$
right? Is the answer $10/3$? How do I maximise
$$\frac13 (\sin 3y_1 + \sin 3y_2 +\cdots + \sin 3y_{10})$$ under the constraints?

Comment: Are you asked to use a trigonometric substitution ?  The answer is not $\frac{10} 3$ but a little bit lower.

Comment: The answer is not 10/3 but a little bit lower. Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is indeed a little lower than the upper bound of $10/3$. You can come close to having it all, but not quite have everything.

> It's actually $9^{2/3}-1\approx 3.3267$.

**Riding the S curve**

Without loss of generality, we may assume that the $x$ values are in ascending order defined by $x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le ... \le x_{10}$. In that case the terms $x_1$ through $x_m$ are all negative for some whole number $m\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, and all subsequent terms are nonnegative.

Suppose, then, that $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$ are two consecutive negative terms. Below we see what happens if we decrease $x_k$ and increase $x_{k+1}$ so that the sum of their cubes is constant:

[image]

Because of the curvature of the function for negative arguments, incrementing or decrementing the cubes equally will impart unequal changes to the uncubed terms: $x_{k+1}$ is increased more than $x_k$ is decreased and therefore the sum is increased by driving these terms farther apart. To maximize the contribution to the sum from the negative terms, therefore, we should drive those terms apart, pushing some of them all the way to $-1$ and others to $0$.

Now let's look at what happens with the nonnegative terms, including those that were pushed from negative to zero in accordance with the above strategy:

[image]

The cubing function now curves the opposite way, so pushing nonnegative terms farther apart will decrease rather than increase the sum of those terms. We should therefore equalize all nonnegative terms to maximize the sum.

So, to optimize both parts of the S curve, we should drive all negative terms to $-1$ and render all the remaining terms equal. Then with $m$ negative terms the remaining $10-m$ terms are given by

$x_k=[m/(10-m)]^{1/3}, k>m$

and the sum is rendered as

$f(m)=-m+(10-m)[m/(10-m)]^{1/3}=m^{1/3}(10-m)^{2/3}-m$

We then try out the possibilities for $m$, given above as $m\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. We discover that $m=1$ gives the maximum result, with a value given in the Spoiler.

**Missed it by that much**

Why did we come close to the upper bound of $10/3$ and yet ultimately we fell short? It was noted above that the number of negative terms had to be a whole number, thus constraining the candidates we could try. But what if we ignored this constraint? If $m$ were a continuous variable we would maximize $f(m)$ above by setting its derivative to zero.

Sure enough, the optimal value of $m$ from this method is not a whole number. It is the fractional number $10/9$. And for $m=10/9$, true to form, we hit $f(m)=10/3$. We meet the trigonometric upper bound after all ... but only by cheating. In the real world where $m$ has to be a whole number, we can only come close by selecting the nearest available whole number, and so we settle for $m=1$ and a sum value slightly less than our ideal one.

Comment: T HANKS FOR THE SOLUTION. But I have a doubt. Some of the negative terms might be pushed to the psoitive side as well . And if the non negative terms are equal then the x (K+1) pushed to right might also become positive. How do you account for this? How do you know that pushing x k+1 ahead of zero is not allowed?

Comment: "To maximize the contribution to the sum from the negative terms, therefore, we should drive those terms apart, pushing some of them all the way to −1 and others to 0."You had proved this for two  variables , how did you extend it to all negative terms?

Comment: You have not even pushed a single number to zero. Then what do you mean by "and others to 0"?

Comment: When a negative number is pushed to zero, it becomes nonnegative and thus gets pulled into equality with the positive numbers. The only termsvthat remain negative when the sum is fully maximized are terms equalling $-1$.

Comment: Thanks , I get it now.

Comment: And, why did you assume sum of two cubes to be constant? It's the sum of ten cubes that's constant.

Answer (score 0):

@RishiShekher What you have done is established an upper bound, to the problem that has to be attained. What the error in your argument is that you never explain whether equality can occur w.r.t the constraint, your argument is analogous to this.  We all know the following inequality is true $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\ge 2$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, but the same inequality could posed as $x+\frac{1}{x}\ge 1$. The difference is the first one, equality can be attained whereas for the second it can't.

P.S: This is not an answer just a comment that points out the error, the comment box couldn't handle the word count

Comment: You could get $\sin(3y_k)=1$ using either $\sin(y_k)=1/2$ or $\sin(y_k)=-1$, which allows you to get the sum of cubes closer to zero. But not exactly because you can't get exactly the right proportion of positive and negative terms. See my development.

Comment: The sum could be $-1/8$ using one negative term. But that's as close as you can get.

Comment: @OscarLanzi yeah I see your point, but I guess the upper bound still need to be justified no, as you have done.